# Probability of people knowing each other through chain of certain length

Tags: probability

$\textbf{The situation:}$ Let's say there's $n$ people, and the probability that two people chosen at random know each other is $p \in (0,1)$.

$\textbf{Question 1:}$ What is the probability that two people chosen at random know each other through a chain of $\leq k$ people, where $k \leq n$? (For example, if $k$ is $1$, the probability is just $p$ because then it is then the probability that two people know each other directly).

$\textbf{Question 2:}$ What is the probability that two people chosen at random know each other through a chain of $\textit{exactly}$ $k$ people?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a stochastic matrix with all entries equal to $p$, except the diagonal which is all 1. Call this matrix $M$. Then $M^2$ gives the probability that two people know each other either directly or through a chain of one intermediate person. Similarly $M^k$ gives the probability tht two people know each other through a chain of $k-1$ intermediate people or less. You can calculate this $M^k$ for small $n$ to see the pattern. Also $M^k - M^{k-1}$ answers question 2.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a little confused with the answer, though... isn't $M^2$ a matrix? Also, how did you come up with the matrix?

Comment: @Lucas Yes, all entries on the diagonal will be meaningless and all off-diagonal entries of $M^k$ will be equal to the probability that two people know eachother through a chain of $k-1$ or fewer intermediate people.

Comment: @Lucas I got the matrix by noting that if you multiply $M*M^k$ then by induction you get the right answer because when you sum up all the ways to get from $i$ to $j$ in $k$ intermediate nodes or less, you get all the paths going from $i$ to a second to last node and then going to $j$ by transitioning (multiplying by $p$) unless you are already at $j$ in which case you multiply by $1$. And this is added up for all second-to-last nodes by properties of matrix multiplication. Hence the diagonal of all 1 in $M$.

Comment: Can you give me an example of like M M^2 and M^3? I'm still a little bit confused when I try to work it out myself. Thanks for your help